# How to set parameter values in RDLC

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have added two text boxes for the date range in the report. To fill the values in the text boxes, I set parameters to the text boxes.

Now the date range is coming from a form named DateRange having two DateTimePickers.

How to set the value of the text boxes in rdlc equal to these DataTimePickers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set parameter value like this.

```
DateTime dtStartDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;     
DateTime dtEndDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;     
ReportParameter[] params = new ReportParameter[2]; 
params[0] = new ReportParameter("StartDate", dtStartDate, false); 
params[1] = new ReportParameter("EndDate", dtEndDate, false); 
this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(params);
```

[Passing Parameters to RDLC](http://dotnetknowledgebox.blogspot.in/2012/01/passing-parameters-to-rdlc.html)

Comment: I have set `parameter` in the `text boxes` from `TextBox Property` (set `Expression` as `Parameter`).

Comment: Showing error `"An error occurred during local report processing." and where will these parameters be shawn.? It's LocalReport.

Comment: Have you created parameter in your RDLC report?

Comment: FWIW, the link no longer resolves, but Wayback Archive has it:
https://web.archive.org/web/20180402025245/http://dotnetknowledgebox.blogspot.in/2012/01/passing-parameters-to-rdlc.html