# how can i use local parameter in rdlc report

Tags: c#, rdlc

i want to use value of variable name ReportTitle in rdlc report

my c# code is:

```
this.Report1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Report1.rdlc";
ReportParameterCollection reportParms1 = new ReportParameterCollection();
reportParms1.Add(new ReportParameter("ReportTitle", "My Report");
this.Report1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParms1);
```

rdlc code:

```
<ReportItems>
<Textbox name="ReportTitle">
<Value>=Parameters!ReportTitle.Value>
</Textbox>
</ReportItems>
```

i am getting exception error in
setParameter()Line

Exception is "Error occured during local report processing"
Inner Exception is "The definition of report is invalid"
Inner Exception is " The Value expression for Textbox refers to an non existing report Parameter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996831/how-to-set-parameter-values-in-rdlc
already in try this

Comment: still got same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a `ReportParameter` in your RDLC before using it:

```
<ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="ReportTitle">
        <DataType>String</DataType>
        <Prompt>ReportTitle</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
</ReportParameters>
```

In Visual Studio you can also use *View > Report Data* instead of directly modifying the RDLC.